# Call dynamically modal bootstrap for log-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I would like know which logic is used to show the modal of login if the user does an action when is not logged. Example with a scenario:

User A is logged on the website, he opens another page and logs out, he comes back to the previous page where was logged and write a comment on shoutbox in ajax. The user is not logged and should be shown a modal (bootstap if possible) with the form log in.

Obviously the check is done with php everything is done, I don't know how to call the modal and open it after the check php if it fail.

I thought a solution, like put the modal in all the pages, and call it with `$('#modal').modal('show');` after the result of ajax, but i think is not the right solution put that modal in all the page, maybe there is a method for call it dynamically

Comment: You're looking for `$.dialog()`.  Please refer to the jQuery docs, here's the one for a dialog box.  Set the `modal: true` option if you'd like it to be a modal dialog  box http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: You could look for the cookie authentication ticket, if not present, you show the modal pop up

Comment: @fabrizio - When saying `modal` do you mean `model`?

Comment: i mean modal boostrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I that you've tagged this wrong then, you don't mean jQuery.  jQuery is a Javascript framework of it's own, separate to bootstrap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can try,

```
$.ajax({
// your ajax code, in php file you check session if not return NotLoggedIn message
   success:function(data) {
       if(data == 'NotLoggedIn') {
          $('#modalbody').html('here is the html of your login form');
          $('#modal').modal('show');
       } else {
          // other code
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Cool, this method is secure?

Comment: You can generalize the `ajax` function and always check in `success` whether the data returned from `php` has `session`, and what you mean by `secure`?

Answer (score 1):

The approach depends greatly on what exactly you are using.

Me, being a symfony2 fan, I would return either a success message or a rendered view containing the modal if the user is not logged in.

On the frontend I would need only to check if the success message was returned, else eval() the message so the rendered view is shown.

This way, from whatever page you call that action you will get the modal as response if user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the following javascript code in a js file along with the rest of you js libs,

```
function showModal(message, closeCaption, options) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var modalDialogHTML = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' +
            '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">' + message + '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">' + (closeCaption ? closeCaption : 'Close') + '</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

        $('body').append(modalDialogHTML);
        $('#myModal').modal(options);

    });
}
```

Then you may call dynamically `showModal("the message");`
when you detect non logged in user.

http://jsfiddle.net/v8USb/

Comment: Thank you for this code, i like so much this logic I'll use it with the code suggested by Ajit S

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies, while user logout, cookies expires. Create a php file which includes login modal code and place on every page like `<?php include("login-modal.php")?>`. Then set when user add comment, a jquery is run to check if user is already logged in or not. if not then open modal login

Comment: or you can open php tag in jquery.

Comment: this is a waste of bandwidth for a site where the user browses hundreds of pages before logging out. And cookies are not the only way to check if user is logged in. What if he logs in with facebook api?